# If $\tan(\alpha)+\cot(\alpha)=p,$ denote $\tan^3(\alpha)+\cot^3(\alpha)$ in terms of $p$

Tags: trigonometry

I wrote the second expression according to the identity:
\begin{align}
& \tan^3(\alpha) + \cot^3(\alpha) \\[10pt]
= {} & \bigl(\tan(\alpha) + \cot(\alpha)\bigr) \bigl( \tan^2(\alpha) - \tan(\alpha) \cot(\alpha) + \cot^2(\alpha)\bigr) \\[10pt]
= {} & p\bigl(\tan^2(\alpha) + \cot^2(\alpha) - 1\bigr).
\end{align} 
Then tried to use the  identity $a^2+b^2=(a-b)^2+2ab$ but that was to no vail. How to solve it?

Comment: You got it!, just note that $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab$ and that $\tan x\cot x=1$

Comment: Equivalently (but perhaps easier to discover), expand $(\tan\alpha+\cot\alpha)^3$ and use $\tan\alpha\cot\alpha=1$.

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl I meant, if I use this second identity this again produces $\tan^2(\alpha)+\cot^2(\alpha)$ in the first expression.

Comment: @Tug'tekin Use the identity $\,(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)\,$ instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=\tan(\alpha)$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Solu}&\text{tion #1:}\\[6pt]
&u+\frac{1}{u}=p\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\left(u+\frac{1}{u}\right)^2=p^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&u^2+\frac{1}{u^2}=p^2-2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&u^2 - u\left(\frac{1}{u}\right) + \frac{1}{u^2} = p^2-3\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\left(u+\frac{1}{u}\right)\left(u^2 - u\left(\frac{1}{u}\right) + \frac{1}{u^2}\right) = p(p^2-3)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&u^3+\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^3 = p(p^2-3)\\[12pt]
\text{Solu}&\text{tion #2:}\\[6pt]
&u+\frac{1}{u}=p\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\left(u+\frac{1}{u}\right)^3=p^3\\[4pt]
\implies\;&u^3+3u^2\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)+3u\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^3=p^3\\[4pt]
\implies\;&u^3+3\left(u+\frac{1}{u}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^3=p^3\\[4pt]
\implies\;&u^3+\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^3=p^3-3p\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)$$

Comment: @Tug'tekin, What are $a+b, ab$ here? Just expand $(a+b)^3$ to check the validity of the formula